# $P(x^2+1)=P(x)Q(x)$ implies $P(x)$ is of even degree

Tags: polynomials

The question is to prove that the polynomial $P(x)$ is of even degree if there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x^2+1) = P(x)Q(x) $.
This was an interview question.
It is easy to show that $P(x)$ can't be linear and that the degree of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ must be equal, also the coefficient of the highest degree term in $Q(x)$ must be $1$. I am not able to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the polynomials need to have real coefficients?

Comment: Assuming you have a real coefficient, consider $x^2 + 1 = p$, where $p$ is the root of the $P(x)$.

Comment: Yes the polynomial is supposed to have real coefficients

Comment: Though considering it was a maths interview, it should have been mentioned

Comment: @AspiringMat , I should have mentioned the college lol.  It's called ISI(Indian Statistical Institute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dietrich Burde points out, there are counterexamples when you consider polynomials with complex coefficients. On the other hand, if you meant $P(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, then it is indeed true that it must have even degree. This will follow from proving that $P$ has no real roots. Use the fact that if $\alpha$ is a root of $P$, then so is $f(\alpha) = \alpha^2+1$. Now, for any real root $\alpha$, you can keep applying $f$ to get new roots. Prove that this process will yield infinitely many distinct roots for $P$, which would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

This is false, as the following example with a linear polynomial $P(x)$ shows, namely
$$
P(x)=ax+1,\; Q(x)=x+b,\; \text{ with } a=\frac{\sqrt{-3}-1}{2}, b=\frac{\sqrt{-3}+1}{2}.
$$
Then $a+1=b$ so that
$$
P(x^2+1)=ax^2+b=P(x)Q(x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement only holds if we insist the coefficients of $P(x)$ are real (counterexample below).

Let's assume $P(x)$ is a real polynomial with degree $n$, where $n$ is odd. We know that all such $P$ have at least one real root, so let $w$ be a real root of $P$. But then
$$P(w^2+1)=P(w)Q(w)=0$$
so $w^2+1$ is also a real root of $P$; and it can't be the same real root as
$$w^2+1=w$$
doesn't have any real solutions.

But now we can just create the sequence
$$w_1=w,\quad w_{k+1}=w_k^2+1$$

which clearly has infinitely many distinct real terms (since $w_{k+1}>w_k$ for all $k$), all of which are roots of $P$; but $P$ has at most $n$ real roots; contradiction.

So $P$ can't be a real polynomial with odd degree. (This is technically enough to answer the question as it's written; but it's also easy enough to find a polynomial $P$ with even degree that works).

---

If polynomials with complex coefficients are allowed, then
$$P(x)=x+c,\quad Q(x)=x-c$$
where $c=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ satisfies the condition.